# How to change li position using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to make a function that foreach time the function is called the first li at the top will be the last one so the first example will look like this

```
<ul>
<li id="2">
<li id="3">
<li id="4">
<li id="5">
<li id="6">
<li id="7">
<li id="1">
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('li:first').appendTo('ul');
```

working example (click anywhere): http://jsbin.com/izize3/1

Comment: What if there is more than one list?

Comment: @Gumbo - then this will not work, it will append the first li to all uls. It needs better selectors, but the idea stays the same, eg `$('#list > li:first').appendTo('#list');` . I might ask: what if we have a ul inside ul? (the question is very broad, to my defence, so I just showed the idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var firstChild = $("ul > li:first-child");
firstChild.appendTo(firstChild.parent("ul"));
```